# Java AlphaNumeric Parsing

Tags: java, string-parsing

I am probably overlooking a simple solution to this problem but I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to parse a command line argument in my java program in a certain format.

I want to parse multiple command line arguments that take a form of "-c3". The letter "c" would represent a particular variable inside the program. The number "3" would represent the value of "c".

Here's how I initially conceptualized parsing the command line arguments:

```
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        String[] parseArg = args[i].split("");
        switch(parseArg[2]){  //parseArg[2] is the alpha character
            case "c" :
               varC = parseArg[3]; //parseArg[3] is  the first digit of the value, varC is the placeholder for command line variable "c" (ie "-c3")
        }
```

I would continue to add multiple case statements for all of the variables that would be given as command line arguments. This seemed like a working solution until I realized that integers with more than one digit would not split correctly.

I've looked over tutorials for .string methods and different ways to parse but I'm still unclear how to parse an argument based on the different of alpha and numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String arg = "-c12345";
String[] parseArg = arg.split("(?<!...)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseArg));
```

result:

```
[-, c, 12345]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand what exactly you wanna try, but this solution will work for you. Remember that index starts with *0*.

```
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
    String[] parseArg = args[i].split("");
    int varC = 0;
    switch(parseArg[1]) {
        case "c" :
           varC = Integer.parseInt(parseArg[2]);
           break;
    }
}
```

You might need to declare *varC* just inside your for loop or even before it.

Comment: This handles a single digit integer but a double digit like "-c38". Also, the the indices I had were correct. The first char is a blank space, second char is "-", third is "c", fourth is first digit, fifth is second digit.